# Run command with limited execution time

Tags: python, bash, zsh

If I were to run some Python through the command line say for example something like this:

```
cat <<'PYSTUFF' | python
print "Hi"
print "There"
print "Friend"
PYSTUFF
```

This works great and outputs the response of the REPL. What I want to do is limit the execution of this command. For example if I wrote:

```
cat <<'PYSTUFF' | python
while(True):
    print "Oh no!"
PYSTUFF
```

That would be no good and would eventually crash something. How do I limit the execution to say "if this takes more than x amount of time, kill it."? I tried using `ulimit -t 2` but that does not seem to achieve what I want.

Comment: [`man timeout`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Biffen Using the `timeout` command worked perfectly. On a mac I used `gtimeout`. My entire command looks like this:

```
cat <<'PYSTUFF' | gtimeout 0.5 python
while(True): print("hi")
PYSTUFF
```

Answer (score 0):

> limit the execution of this command.

Starting from Python 2.6+ you could use the `multiprocessing` module:

```
cat <<'PYSTUFF' | python
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def task():
    while True:
        print "oh no!"
        sleep(0.5)

p = Process(target=task)
p.start()
p.join(1)
print "*** Aborted"
p.terminate()
PYSTUFF
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control this from the shell, launch the python script into the background, sleep for a while, then kill the backgrounded process:

```
# a sample command that generates some output
{ while :; do date; sleep 1; done; } &

# let it run for a while, see if it's still running, and kill it if it is
sleep 10 && kill -0 $! 2>/dev/null && kill $!
```